# Is there an easy way to uglify / minify an electron project?

Tags: electron, uglifyjs

I've written an electron application which is packed via `electron-packager` and shipped to users. Now of course I'd like to put at least some very basic Protection on my sources, ideally merging all my JS files into one big file, and uglify this file.

Of course this would break all `require` Statements in the  HTML and JS files (even if I only minify / uglify without merging, the JS files get renamed).

Is there any convenient way to merge those files upon building the app, without rewriting my working environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your project with webpack. I'm not sure which framework has been used at your renderer UI framework.
But you can use this plugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/.

This will help to make uglify your source code.
After webpack build then you just need to change the entry point for main and renderer.